# Reading session var in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I read the session data set in PHP from Javascript. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] ="orange";
?>

<script>
var username = '<%= Session["test"] %>';
alert(username );
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you add it to the html (for example a `data` attribute) or as a javascript variable, you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo it out:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] ="orange";
?>

<script>
var username = '<?php echo $_SESSION["test"]; ?>';
alert(username);
</script>
```

BTW, you used ASP.NET inline expression tags. You can use `<?=` `?>` for PHP if you have short tags enabled.

Comment: I'm using LAMP and was learning Javascript to do stuff client side. My files are all php. Could you tell me what is ASP.NET inline expression tags. And anything else I need to know when using JS in PHP files. Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET opening/closing tags: `<% .... %>` PHP opening/closing tags: `<?php .... ?>`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<script>
<?php echo "var username = '".$_SESSION["test"]."';";
alert (username);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Following are your mistakes

1. You have written `Session["test"]` instead of `$_SESSION['test']`
2. you are using `%` symbol instead of `?`

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] ="orange";
?>

<script>
var username = '<?= $_SESSION["test"] ?>';
alert(username );
</script>
```